# Sorting file lines numerically by chromosome?

Tags: linux, sort, bioinformatics

I have genetic variant data with several columns, currently my variants/lines are in the wrong order and need to be sorted by chromosome. I've tried a few ways to do this using answers from similar questions but none work, mostly giving me empty files.

currently my chromosome order is:

```
1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
21
22
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

these lines need to be sorted in order ascending from 1 to 22.

I've tried:

```
sort -k 1,1 -k2,2n file.avinput > test.avinput

sortBed -i file.avinput >  test.avinput 

sort -k1,1V -k2,2g file.avinput > test.avinput

bedtools sort -g file.bed> test.avinput #gives *ERROR: Need -i BED file.
```

These run but when I try `head test.avinput` it gives me nothing, or when I check with `awk '{print $1}' test.avinput | sort -u` the order is still wrong - what else can I try to change this?

An example of how a couple lines looks is this:

File.avinput: #3 columns are chromosome, start and end  - I have no header

```
1    10  11
10   200 201
2    20   21
22   2000 2001
```

Expected ordered output

```
1    10  11
2    20   21
10   200 201
22   2000 2001
```

Currently trying any form of using `sort -n` gives me an empty file.

Comment: I don't know which file your "chromosome order" numbers correspond to, but you need the `-n` numeric flag to sort them numerically versus lexically.

Comment: Thank you for you response, I have one file ``` file.avinput ``` with the chromosomes - I'll edit my question to give more detail of this. Each line is a variant with columns of chromosome number followed by position of the variant at that chromosome. I have since tried a few with ```-n``` but having the same trouble

Comment: It's good to anonymize your data, but be sure to represent the structure, too -- commas, tabs, columns, etc.

Comment: @DN1 Post a few lines of the files you want sorted. It makes it much easier to understand your problem - especially for non-bioinformaticians.

Comment: Thank you for these comments, I've had a go. Unfortunately I only have a biology background with little linux experience so not sure if I have copied this over with full clarity, but hopefully it's more clear now. I believe the file should be tab separated

Comment: @DN1 are you sure you are looking at the correct file(s)? regardless of whether or not it gives you your desired order, the `sort` command should output *some* ordering of any non-empty file. If you simply run `sort -n file.avinput` do you see output in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED according to changed task.

File `file1` with your data created:

```
$ cat file1
1    10  11
10   200 201
2    20   21
22   2000 2001
```

Now we sort the file lines and write results to `file2`:

```
$ cat file1|sort -n > file2
```

Or we can even simplify it:

```
$ sort -n file1 > file2
```

Checking the results in `file2`:

```
$ cat file2
1    10  11
2    20   21
10   200 201
22   2000 2001
```

Comment: Thank you for this, do you know how I can apply this to a large file, I have 16945 lines with more columns than just the chromosome column - sorry I've only amended my question to detail this now

Comment: it is still not clear what you need. I showed only approach, if you want to have file lines sorted numerically ascending based on numbers in first column, you only need to `cat file1|sort -n > file2`. It may help to understand you better, if you provide with 1) input file1 containing 4-5 lines ordered incorrectly; 2) desired properly ordered result file2, you want to get from file1.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've tried to re-do my example data for more clarity. I've also tried the line you provide in this comment but it gives an empty file

Comment: When I run just ```sort -n file1``` I see it working, but then I add the ```> file2``` file2 is empty